# How to make GraphQL api for a neo4j database

Tags: neo4j, graphql, apollo-server

I made a database in neo4j desktop. The database is locally saved and now I want to make a GraphQL api for it.

I tried to follow [this](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/getting-started/) and it doesn't seem to be working. I am also trying to use the introspect tool from [this page](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/introspector/). I'm using VS Code.

Here is index.js:

```
import { startStandaloneServer } from '@apollo/server/standalone';
import { Neo4jGraphQL } from "@neo4j/graphql";
import { toGraphQLTypeDefs } from "@neo4j/introspector";
import neo4j from "neo4j-driver";

const driver = neo4j.driver(
    "neo4j://localhost:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password")
);

const sessionFactory = () =>
    driver.session({ defaultAccessMode: neo4j.session.READ });

// We create a async function here until "top level await" has landed
// so we can use async/await
async function main() {
    const readonly = true; // We don't want to expose mutations in this case
    const typeDefs = await toGraphQLTypeDefs(sessionFactory, readonly);
    const driver = neo4j.driver(
        "bolt://localhost:7687",
        neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password")
    );
    
    const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({ typeDefs, driver });

    const server = new ApolloServer({
        schema: await neoSchema.getSchema(),
    });
    
    const { url } = await startStandaloneServer(server, {
        context: async ({ req }) => ({ req }),
        listen: { port: 4000 },
    });
    
    console.log(` Server ready at ${url}`); 
}

main();
```

and this is what I get when I run it in terminal:
its either:
this
[image: this]
or this
[image: or this]

I always have the db up and running when I try this. I tried to use the neo4j GraphQL toolbox extension for the desktop app and I could get queries to work but I don't know how to deploy for use with a website or an application.

Answer (score 0):

As for the second error, you are missing:

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
```

At the top of your code.

Comment: this worked and i got the apollo server running, but whenever i open localhost in my browser and try to run a query i get this error: ailed to connect to server. Please ensure that your database is listening on the correct host and port and that you have compatible encryption settings both on Neo4j server and driver. Note that the default encryption setting has changed in Neo4j 4.0. Caused by: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:7687

Comment: I have the same issue following the same instructions as the OP -  ECONNREFUSED ::1:7687

Answer (score 0):

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
    "neo4j://localhost:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password")
);
```

try

```
const driver = neo4j.driver(
    "bolt://localhost:7687",
    neo4j.auth.basic("neo4j", "password")
);
```

note that the default username / password is neo4j / neo4j